# .htaccess being overpowered by file structure in apache2

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

I have a .htaccess file and am using mod rewrite to redirect `/tags` to `/tags/`. When the directory contains a file called `tags.php`, it doesn't work, but when I remove that file it does. What setting do I need to change to make the .htaccess file overpower the file structure? I'm running Apache2 on Ubuntu 11.10 with PHP.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^tags/([a-zA-Z0-9-_.\ ]+)$ tags/$1/ [R]
    RewriteRule ^tags/([a-zA-Z0-9-_.\ ]+)/([0-9]*)?$ tag.php?tag=$1&page=$2
    RewriteRule ^tags$ tags/ [R]
    RewriteRule ^tags/$ tags.php
```

Comment: What is currently in your .htaccess file?

Comment: Edited with contents of .htaccess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable `Multiviews` in the server configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an `L` to your tags rule to stop further processing i.e.

```
RewriteRule ^tags$ tags/ [R,L]
```

Comment: When you access just `/tags`, does it redirect to `/tags/` and then display the result of `tags.php`, OR is there no redirect at all. You can use Fiddler or something similar to see the redirects.

Answer (score 0):

Your rules are in the wrong order, and you've forgotten the [L] to stop processing the rewrite rules. Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^tags$ tags/ [R, L]
RewriteRule ^tags/$ tags.php [QSA]
RewriteRule ^tags/([a-zA-Z0-9-_.\ ]+)$ tags/$1/ [R,L]
RewriteRule ^tags/([a-zA-Z0-9-_.\ ]+)/([0-9]*)?$ tag.php?tag=$1&page=$2 [L]
```

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem. My .htaccess only doesn't work when the directory also contains a file called tags.php. If there is no file by that name, all redirects works fine.

Comment: How about trying to add (= override) the `DirectoryIndex` directive?